# Fastest way to rotate big size bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am working with large size images and when I try to rotate them `(applying matrix on the bitmap)` a lot of seconds occurs.
I've seen that android system gallery can accomplish this task in a very fast manner instead. How is it possible?

I thought to perform the rotation on an asyncTask, applying only the ImageView rotation (which doesn't take long time) on the main thread, but if the app is killed before the asyncTask get to the end, the app fall in an inconsistent state.

This is my bitmap rotation code, which takes long time execution for large bitmaps:

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.setRotate(90);
bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing modifications to a large image, create a low quality bitmap copy of it and use it for showing instant rotation or other editing effects. Once user is stopped motion (or left slider control)  replace the low quality bitmap with the original image with same effects applied to it. This will significantly improve user experience. Try and let me know.

This might sound like a deviation from the original requirement- you can draw a rectangle instead of rotating the whole image in real time. In the end, what user needs is an indication of how much his image has rotated. This will be faster and can easily be done on UI thread without lag.

This is the simplest rotation on canvas code

```
canvas.save(); //save the position of the canvas
canvas.rotate(angle, X + (imageW / 2), Y + (imageH / 2)); //rotate the canvas
canvas.drawBitmap(imageBmp, X, Y, null); //draw the image on the rotated canvas
canvas.restore();  // restore the canvas position.
```

Comment: This is a good idea to improve user experience, of course. But the main problem is that when I work on the original image at the end, the task may require a lot of time to complete and I have these complications:
- if i perform the operation on the main thread the user have to wait
- if i perform the operation on an asyncTask, the app should be killed before its completion and the changes would be lost

Comment: This might sound like a deviation from the original requirement- you can draw a rectangle instead of rotating the whole image in real time. in the end what user needs is an indication of how much his image has rotated. This will be faster and easily done on UI thread without lag..

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, my question is: "How to perform bitmap rotation in a fast way, as the system gallery is able to do". Anyway I'm stil a lot confused by your hints.
What i need in the end is to perform the rotation on the big size bitmap, not give the user an indication about rotation like you said.
Furthermore I allow only 90, 180, 270, 360 degrees rotation just like the gallery allow to do. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Ok. I got it. For that I should know how you do the rotation. Taking a look at your rotation code might tell us something..

Comment: I also added my rotation code. Your code is for canvas rotation, but the slow execution problem I have concerns bitmap rotation not canvas (or ImageView) rotation. I am already able to perform canvas rotation quickly

Comment: My original answer still applies. You can create a low quality bitmap and perform the transformation on it. Keep track of all the transformations and do those on original bitmap when user saves it.

Comment: Check the gallery app source code and see how they do it. I was not able to get the source. :(

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your help. I'm very graceful to you for your effort, maybe is not so simple reproduce the behavior of the system gallery.

Comment: you can copy the part of code that does this rotation from gallery app. You will have to download it from source.android.com... good luck

Comment: here's a tiny library I made that allows rotating of large images, as long as you can hold a single bitmap (doesn't require to create a new bitmap that takes the same amount of bytes) : https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations  . It's probably a bit slower than what Google has made, but it's safer in terms of memory. It also has a few other features.