# how can i use property Animation to rotate view around the point?

Tags: android, animation

use `Tween Animation` code:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation (0,90,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration (2000);
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter (true);
    image2.startAnimation (rotateAnimation);
}
```

of cause use `Tween Animation` can do that,but `Tween Animation` hava a defect.
  For example the following gif click event does not move.
  So I want use `property Animation` to do that,but I found `property Animation` can only rotate around the Center.
  how can i use property Animation to rotate view around the point?
[image: tween Animation]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099814/rotate-image-around-a-center-of-another-image

Answer (score 0):

I think from your question that you want rotation around the mouse pointer.

Try this, I think it should work but I haven't had a chance to try it yet.

```
...
Animation rotateAnimation  = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f);
...
```