# Rotating around a view (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, rotation

I have a image named 'red'. This image is rotating now, by 5 degrees. 
Here is the code:

```
red.setRotation(red.getRotation() - 5);
```

When it's rotating, its rotating on the center point of the image.  But what if i wanted to make the center point to be another image or view.  So 'red' will rotate around that image.

Comment: The you must google a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099814/rotate-image-around-a-center-of-another-image

Comment: @Mariano But i'm not using Matrix.  Or should i just add the matrix code under my code?