# How to rotate Bitmap without creating a new one?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, rotation

I'm using this to get rotated `Bitmap` from existed one :

```
private Bitmap getRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int angle) {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
    }
```

Is it possible to do it without creating new bitmap?

I was trying to redraw the same mutable image with `Canvas`:

```
Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, config);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(mRotation,source.getWidth()/2,source.getHeight()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(targetBitmap, matrix, new Paint());
```

but this approach had just resulted in corrupted bitmap. 
So is there any possibilities to achieve it?

Comment: try to get the bits and apply a matrix rotation algorithm

Comment: This answer might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664006/fastest-way-to-rotate-big-size-bitmap/10664055#10664055

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest rotation on canvas code, without creating a new bitmap

```
canvas.save(); //save the position of the canvas
canvas.rotate(angle, X + (imageW / 2), Y + (imageH / 2)); //rotate the canvas
canvas.drawBitmap(imageBmp, X, Y, null); //draw the image on the rotated canvas
canvas.restore();  // restore the canvas position.
```

Comment: It's not rotating the bitmap itself but just draw it rotated inside view. What I want is to rotate bitmap and save it.